# Confusing use of && and | operators

Tags: bash

I haven't been able to dig up documentation regarding this particular use of `|` operator. Can anyone explain what `|` does in this particular context?

[image]

Comment: Please, post the commands as code, not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` is the pipeline operator. It connects the standard output of `true` (which is empty) to the standard input of `echo` (which happily ignores it).

Comment: Does that mean "|" is functionally equivalent to ";" in bash?

Comment: @Jimmy: No, `;` just separates commands, it doesn't connect their outputs and inputs. Try `echo 1 | cat` versus `echo 1; cat`.

Comment: Got it, thanks!